# how to sum hours to a start shift column that contains a text

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add 9 hours to this column and if there's a text like (off, annual, ..etc), then put the same text. but i found an error in the generated column, is there any one have an idea to to solve this problem[image]

Comment: If you have the cells formatted correctly, then just do =C1+9 where C1 contains the initial time. Can do the same with days or weeks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
try Time.From([Start Shift]) + #duration(0, 9, 0, 0) otherwise [Start Shift]
```

Comment: it's worked but didn't sum 9 hours to the original shifts

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you give an example input and output which is wrong?

Comment: for example

Start Shift  End Shift
Off  Off
Annual  Annual
8:00  8:00
10:00  10:00

Comment: Thanks. Have edited.

Comment: there's an error in otherwise command, when i removed it, the caculation worked normally but just i need to solve the error of the text like off or annual

Comment: @MahmoudBadr what is an "otherwise command"?

Comment: @MahmoudBadr Did you include the `try` expression as I wrote it? `otherwise` works with `try`.

Comment: Aha, I'll test it and feedback you as i didn't include try

Comment: Many thanks, it's working now